# Make Div 100% of Unknown Size?

Tags: html, css

I have a box that says "Test" in it. I want to make the width 100% of its containing div. im not sure how to do this? The jsFiddle below shows what i want to do. I also do not want to use any Javascript.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a6ZCR/3/

Here is some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/CSS/Global/Global.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="Header">
        <div id="HeaderInner">
            <a href="#" class="HeaderLink Main">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="HeaderLink Main">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="HeaderLink Main">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="HeaderLink Main">Link</a>

            <a href="#" class="HeaderLink Side">Log In</a>
            <a href="#" class="HeaderLink Side">Register</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Menu">

    </div>

    <div id="Body">
        <div id="BodyPadding">
            <div class="BasicBox">
                Test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Layout */
html, body, #Wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#Header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 965px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #333;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#HeaderInner {
    display: block;
    width: 965px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#Content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 965px;
    height: 100%;
}

#Menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 220px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
}

#Body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 220px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#BodyPadding {
    padding: 30px;
}
/* Layout End */

/* Links */
.HeaderLink.Main {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 35px;
    color: #E1E1E1;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}

.HeaderLink.Main:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    border-top: 4px solid #DC3522;
    line-height: 43px;
}

.HeaderLink.Side {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #E1E1E1;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}

.HeaderLink.Side:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
/* Links End */

/* Objects */
.BasicBox {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #DDD;
}
/* Objects End */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div`s are 100% of the width of their containing context element unless you do something to change it.

Your problem is that the containing context element is `#Body` which is absolutely positioned and this removes it from the normal page flow and makes it only as wide as its contents. So your 100% width on `.BasicBox` is 100% of auto on an absolutely positioned element.

So, `#Body` is the thing that you need to make as wide as you need it.

Comment: how can i make the "Test" box as wide as the #Body dynamicly without any specific widths, the reason being is because i dont know how big the #body div is. this is a multi-monitor page. it adjusts to the resolution.

Comment: Test is already as wide as `#Body`. Do you mean you want `#Body` to be wider and fill the right hand side?

Comment: Yes that is what i meant, the left menu div is 220px and i want the other leftover space to the right filled by the #body div

Comment: Personally, I would remove the styles from `#Body` and give it a `margin-left: 200px` and a `margin-top: 50px`

Comment: OK let me try that. in the meantime, can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: Do you want the white background to cover the entire right, or a grey 30px padding and then the white background `.BasicBox` inside that?

Comment: I don't think this answer is true, I was able to get this element to fill the page without changing positioning or putting a fixed width on it

Comment: Just because you can do it another way doesn't make a different way untrue. It very much depends upon what final effect the poster wishes.

Comment: i got it to work Klors, i deleted the styles and added the margins and it works how i want it now. Thanks!

Comment: No problem Moussa, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the working fiddle, no set widths, just auto or 100%, pure CSS. I didn't have to change much** http://jsfiddle.net/shayl/a6ZCR/4/

The first thing I noticed was that #Body was only getting the width of the content because the width was set to auto, which means the width was coming from the size of the word "test" and not its parent container.

```
#Body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 220px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

So I changed it to width 100% to fix that

```
#Body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 220px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Then I did the same thing with BodyPadding because it didn't have a width and a height

```
#BodyPadding {
    padding: 30px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

And finally I changed "auto" to "inherit" on this tag to get the heights from its parents:

```
 .BasicBox {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #DDD;
}
```

Here is all the working CSS:

```
            /* Layout */
             html, body, #Wrapper {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%;
                min-width: 1000px;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: #F4F4F4;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
            #Header {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                min-width: 965px;
                height: 50px;
                background-color: #333;
                z-index: 1000;
            }
            #HeaderInner {
                display: block;
                width: 965px;
                height: 50px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #Content {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50px;
                left: 0;
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                min-width: 965px;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #Menu {
                position: fixed;
                top: 50px;
                left: 0;
                width: 220px;
                height: auto;
                min-height: 100%;
                background-color: #FFF;
                border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
            }
            #Body {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50px;
                left: 220px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
            }
            #BodyPadding {
                padding: 30px;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
            /* Layout End */

            /* Links */
             .HeaderLink.Main {
                float: left;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0 35px;
                color: #E1E1E1;
                text-align: center;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-decoration: none;
                line-height: 50px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
                -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
            }
            .HeaderLink.Main:hover {
                color: #FFF;
                border-top: 4px solid #DC3522;
                line-height: 43px;
            }
            .HeaderLink.Side {
                float: right;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0 20px;
                color: #E1E1E1;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                line-height: 50px;
                transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
                -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
            }
            .HeaderLink.Side:hover {
                color: #FFF;
            }
            /* Links End */

            /* Objects */
             .BasicBox {
                width: inherit;
                height: inherit;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 20px;
                background-color: #FFF;
                border-bottom: 4px solid #DDD;
            }
            /* Objects End */
```

Comment: Please explain the changes, and why they matter. Doing so will make this answer much more useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
.BasicBox {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Right now you have `padding: 20px`.  If you want .BasicBox to fill it's container, the padding is throwing it off.  I would set padding to `0`.